# Usando Method References en Java ¿Cómo se sabe que valores se deben enviar al método?

Tags: java

¡Hola!
Estaba leyendo la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) sobre Method References, y sigo con dudas.
Cuando se usa algo como:

```
Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, Person::compareByAge);
```

En vez de:

```
Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray,
    (Person a, Person b) -> {
        return a.getBirthday().compareTo(b.getBirthday());
    }
);
```

¿Cómo se mandan "a" y "b"?
Se toman del array, que en este caso es "rosterAsArray" ¿es así?
¿Se van tomando secuencialmente del array?

Answer (score 8):

La parte que te falta son **interfaces funcionales**:

```
Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, Person::compareByAge);
```

es equivalente a

```
Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray,
  (Person a, Person b) -> 
    return Person.compareByAge(a, b);
  });
```

que es equivalente* a

```
Arrays.sort(
  rosterAsArray,
  new Comparator<Person>() {
      public boolean compare(Person a, Person b) {
        return Person.compareByAge(a, b);
      }
  });
```

Una interfaz funcional solo necesita implementar un método (los otros ya vienen definido en Object, o tienen implementación *default*) para estar completa.

Desde siempre se podían crear implementaciones anónimas de interfaces (y subclases) mediante el ejemplo usado en el tercer fragmento de código, definiendo los métodos en el momento de crear la instancia.

A partir de Java 8, en el caso de interfaces funcionales, se pueden usar otros métodos (como los lambdas, o referenciando un método) para crear estas clases anónimas. Esto lo que hace, funcionalmente (internalmente es algo diferente), es como si crearas una clase que implementa la interfaz funcional esperada, y con el lambda o el método definido se implementa el método que falta. Como son interfaces en las que solo "falta" un método, no hace falta especificar el nombre del método.

Así, en

```
Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, Person::compareByAge);
```

el método sort espera que lo segundo sea un *Comparator*, y lo que hace el JVM es crear ese comparator, usando como implementación del método *compare* el método *compareByAge* de *Person*.

El código de *Arrays.sort* solo ve que le llega una instancia de *Comparator*, e invoca el método *compare()*. No sabe cómo se creó esa instancia; para él los tres ejemplos de arriba son exactamente iguales.

Si ves otros métodos de streams, ves que aceptan parámetros como *IntFunction*, *Predicate*, etc. Son otras interfaces funcionales creadas para que sea facil combinar streams con lambdas y referencias a parámetros, haciendo el código más sencillo.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad...
**static  void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)** <-- método que estas usando.

@param a es un array, digamos el array de tipo 'Persona' en el caso del ejemplo que se usará para ejecutar el segundo parámetro **C**
@param c es un Comparator del tipo 'Persona' en el caso del ejemplo, se usa para comparar los objetos del arreglo del parámetro **a**.

Comparator es una interfaz muy especial que te pide que definas el método compare(), con la llegada de las expresiones lambda se ha logrado reducir la cantidad de código que hay que implementar para tan simplemente Comparar objetos por determinados atributos, por ejemplo podíamos llegar a tener NombreComparator, ApellidoComparator, EdadComparator, etc solo para realizar comparaciones, el mundo de las expresiones lamba reduce significativamente todo este código que hay que escribir. **más adelante pongo un ejemplo**

Tú al escribir lo siguiente

```
(Person a, Person b) -> {
        return a.getBirthday().compareTo(b.getBirthday());
    }
```

Es como si realizarás estos pasos

```
1. Crear una Clase que implementa la interfaz Comparator
2. El método sobre-escrito compare() es todo lo que esta dentro de las llaves {}
   es más el método en realidad compare(Person a, Person b).
Puedes verlo como
public class PersonAgeComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
        return a.getBirthday().compareTo(b.getBirthday());
    }
}
Puedes ver que todo esa clase que debías haber creado e importado solo lo haz hecho en 3 simples líneas de código.
Eso son parte de la potencia de las exp lambda
```

para realizar esos dos pasos tú tendrías que crear un archivo implementar la interfaz Comparator y explícitamente declarar el método e implementarlo, luego importarlo donde lo tengas que usar, y si te das cuenta aquí ya habrías utilizado unas 10 o 15 líneas de código adicional con lo que tan solo se puede hacer en una o dos linea con expresiones lamba.

Sí, Person a y Person b parámetros del método **compare()** de la interfaz **Comparator** son llenados por el array **"T[] a"** que recibe como parámetro el método **sort**

Entonces ahora viene el ejemplo que te prometí.
[Ejemplo - Java Blog](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-comparator-interface-y-lambdas/)

Dado que sería muy extenso ponerlo por acá te comparto el enlace donde se te puede aclarar las dudas.

Comment: No explicas dónde interviene el método Persona::compareByAge

Comment: por que no pregunta por ese método. PD: Gracias por la edición no me di cuenta que puse Compare en vez de Comparator al nombre de la interfaz.